# Getting sum of all numbers contained in substrings of S on a segment

Tags: data-structures

I have a string of digits $S$ and *K* queries $l_i, r_I$ - get the sum of all numbers contained in segment of $S$ from $l_i$ to $r_i$.

For example, $S$ = 1034, $l = 1$, $r = 3$. So answer will be $1 + 10 + 103 + 3$ (note: $03$ was not counted, as it starts with $0$)

It has an obvious solution with $O(K\cdot N)$ performance, but I need the faster one. It looks like I need to use ***segment tree*** for storing these sums, but I can't figure out how to do it when $|\ S\ |>2$. If it's possible to use segment tree I'll get an $O(K\log{N})$ solution, it'll be great.

Any ideas of how to use segment tree here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$O(N \log K)$ running time looks achievable.

Hints:

- Suppose you know the answer to the query $l,m$ and the query $m+1,r$.  Can you work out the answer to the query $l,r$ efficiently?  Would precomputation help?  What information do you need to know?
- Use a balanced binary tree, where each digit is at a leaf.  At each internal node $\eta$, you will store the answer to the query $l_\eta,r_\eta$, where $l_\eta$ is the leftmost leaf under $\eta$ and $r_\eta$ is the rightmost leaf under $\eta$.  Also, story the sum of all numbers that can be made by starting at index $i$ (for $l_\eta \le i \le r_\eta$) and ending at index $r_\eta$, as well as the sum of all numbers that can be made by starting at $l_\eta$ and ending at some index $j$ (where $l_\eta \le j \le r_\eta$).

Now for any particular query $l,r$, the answer can be obtained efficiently given only $O(\lg K)$ numbers in the tree.

I'll let you have the joy of working out the rest, since this sounds like a programming contest problem and you should probably make some effort on your own.

Comment: Still can't figure out how to work out the answer knowing answer to $l, m$ and $m+1, r$. Can you give more details?

Comment: Can you help me with this? @D.W.